# Monitor sender's attachment (names only) with Gmail API or Mail Audit API (or with other APIs)?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-admin-audit-api

I'm trying to create an app to monitor employee's file attachments using Google's APIs.

I know that I could download all the emails from the audited user list using Mail Audit API and run scripts on the mails but would there be a better way to get sender's email address with attached file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately, the only options available are the ones you have already suggested.**

However, what you can do is to file a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102) and provide all the necessary details about your use-case and what is it that you want to achieve.